# SQL - how to use max (aggregate) to extract ALL info

Tags: sql, nested, subquery

Having this very simple table:

```
NAME1   NAME2   AGE
Lars    Thomsen 57
Lars    Hansen  45
Per     Olsen   57
Per     Olsen   56
Per     Olsen   58
```

How do I write an SQL-sentence that extracts all info about the eldest of each NAME1?
What I want is this result:

```
NAME1   NAME2   AGE
Lars    Thomsen 57
Per     Olsen   58
```

Thanks

Comment: What if there are duplicates with the same age?

Answer (score 0):

For this simple table (let's call it `t`) it looks quite easy:

```
select  t.*
  from  t
  join (select name1, max(age) as max_age
          from t
         group by name1) t_grp
    on t.name1 = t_grp.name1
   and t.age   = t_grp.max_age
```

If you are using Oracle, it could also be

```
select  *
  from  t
 where (name1, age) in 
         (select name1, max(age)
            from t
           group by name1)
```